# Android Navigation Advanced Sample Dependency Injection (Hilt) on config changes issue

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-bottomnav

having a problem with [Navigation Advanced Sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/NavigationAdvancedSample) provided by Google developers.
Main problem is that in regular case senario for Hilt dependency injection we can simply:

1. Create Custom `FragmentFactory`
2. Create Custom `NavHostFragment`
3. Asigne it to `FragmentContainerView` by using `android:name="com.package.CustomNavHostFragment"`

But how I can do it by using this [Navigation Advanced Sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/NavigationAdvancedSample) ?

Because now on Activity recreate I'm getting typical HILT `error at package.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:23)`

EDIT:

More about the problem. By this provided [simple](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/NavigationAdvancedSample) we should use
[NavigationExtension.kt](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/main/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt) and setup everything by using `BottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController`

And problem is that we need to use the default `NavHostFragment` in order to create a container for each navigation graph.
Is it possible somehow to use custom `NavHostFragment`? If yes, how can I overite that `NavHostFragment.onCreate()` mechanism?
I'm talking about [this line](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/f4fa4f77e6f5dc6d63f2e7b46124e46edff1ae97/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt#L232) in [NavigationExtension.kt](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/main/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt) class

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Please describe it better than just providing a link to a big repository..

Comment: Problem:
On config changes (rotation, dark/light theme update etc.) my app crashes because I don't use FragmentFactory with custom NavHostFragment. My question how it could by done by using [link](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/main/NavigationAdvancedSample)

Comment: The link just points to the entire repository, I am sorry but one can't analyze all and then provide a solution. Please point to a specific class. And why aren't you using the default way with a `FragmentFactory` and a custom `NavHostFragment`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want to create a custom `NavHostFragment`? Yes, that is possible but you don't need to overwrite `NavHostFragment.onCreate()`. Create a custom `NavHostFragment` with the following steps: First, create a `MainFragmentFactory`

### MainFragmentFactory

```
class MainFragmentFactory @Inject constructor(
    //... your dependencies
) : FragmentFactory() {
    override fun instantiate(classLoader: ClassLoader, className: String): Fragment = when(className) {
        MyFragment::class.java.name -> MyFragment(//.. your dependencies)
        MySecondFragment::class.java.name -> MySecondFragment(/...)
        // other fragments

        else -> super.instantiate(classLoader, className)
    }
}
```

Then you need to attach your fragmentFractory to your custom `MainNavHostFragment`

### MainNavHostFragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainNavHostFragment : NavHostFragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mainFragmentFactory: MainFragmentFactory

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        childFragmentManager.fragmentFactory = mainFragmentFactory
    }
}
```

Now you need to add your custom `NavHostFragment` to your `activity_main.xml`

### Activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".framework.ui.view.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        <!-- Add path to your custom NavHostFragment here -->
        android:name="com.example.app.framework.ui.view.utils.MainNavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/wrapContent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        <!-- Your NavGraph -->
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemHorizontalTranslationEnabled="false"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu_logged_out" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Dagger-Hilt will now create all your fragments and instantiate it.